# add error marker to specific line in a SourceViewer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Hi I want to add error marker to my source viewer.
I used the code [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t30082.html)

Everything works fine except the line number..

```
final ErrorAnnotation errorAnnotation = new ErrorAnnotation(1, "Learn how to spell \"text!\"");

    // lets underline the word "texst"
    this.myAnnotationModel.addAnnotation(errorAnnotation, new Position(10, 2));

    final ErrorAnnotation errorAnnotation1 = new ErrorAnnotation(6, "Learn how to spell \"text!\"");

    // lets underline the word "texst"
    this.myAnnotationModel.addAnnotation(errorAnnotation1, new Position(34, 3));
```

All the error markers are shown in the first line only.

Can you please suggest how to get the error marker shown at the correct line.
Below is ErrorAnnotation Class.
The 1st parameter to the ErrorAnnotation constructor, is line number. But the getLine() is not used anywhere (ref. the code found in the link above). I m not sure where and how to use it. If this is not the way to get the annotation in specific line, could you please suggest how it can be done.

```
public class ErrorAnnotation extends Annotation {
    private final IMarker   marker;
    private String          text;
    private int             line;
    private Position        position;

    public ErrorAnnotation(final IMarker marker) {
        this.marker = marker;
    }

    public ErrorAnnotation(final int line, final String text) {
        super(ERROR_TYPE, true, null);
        this.marker = null;
        this.line = line;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public IMarker getMarker() {
        return this.marker;
    }

    public int getLine() {
        return this.line;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return ERROR_IMAGE;
    }

    public int getLayer() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return ERROR_TYPE;
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }

    public void setPosition(final Position position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that the first parameter to `Position` is a character offset (not a line number)?

Comment: Yes. I am including my ErrorAnnotation class, to my Question. I have just pasted the code i found in the link mentioned above. The 1st parameter to the ErrorAnnotation constructor, is line number. But the getLine() is not used anywhere. I m not sure where and how to use it. If this is not the way to get the annotation in specific line, could you please suggest how it can be done.

Comment: You must work out the character offset of the line and use that in the `Position`